# showing the error of specific field in django form

Tags: django, django-views

How can i check the empty field of html form in the django
for example
let us suppose i have two fields username and passoword

```
<input type="text" name="username">
<input type="password" name="password'>
```

and now i want to check them in django
first way is

```
username = request.POST['username']
password = request.POST['password']

#for checking 
if (username) and (password): 
    pass
else:
    error = 'username or password doesn't exit'
```

but the problem is this we can't identify that which field is not present
means i can't show the error like this
error ='username is not present'
error = 'password is not present'

and the another way i found is this

```
if email:
    if password:
       pass
    else:
       error = 'password doesn't exit'
else:
    error = 'email is not present'
```

but if i have more fields in the form then this is difficult

so please tell me the way to show the error of specific field is possible

and my another question
if there is an error in the form
then can show the prefilled information to the user filled in form
so that user doesn't have to completely fill it again

for example in this form

```
@login_required(login_url = 'login')
def create_teacher(request):
    user = request.user
    if user.rejected_once == False or user.user_role == Teacher:
        if request.method == 'POST':
            graduation = request.POST['graduation']
            image =  request.FILES.get("image",None)
            if (graduation)is not '' and (image) is not None:
                user.qualification = graduation
                user.photo = image
                user.request_as_teacher = True
                user.save()
                return redirect('home')
            else:
                print('no')
    else:
        pass
    return render(request, 'user/teacher.html')
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Create either a [django-form](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.is_valid) or a [djangorestframework-serializer](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#validation) for your input data. The validation that you need is builtin to these classes e.g. checking of missing field, checking blank / null field, checking data type of field, etc.

This is highly extensible as you can customize the validation by adding custom logic that you want, add new fields with specified data types as needed, set what is allowed to be null and what isn't, set default values for missing fields, add custom error messages, etc.

```
from django import forms
from rest_framework import serializers

class InputForm(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField()
    password = forms.CharField()

# Or if using djangorestframework
class InputSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    username = serializers.CharField()
    password = serializers.CharField()
```

Initialize it with the data that you want to validate and call `is_valid()`.

```
form = InputForm(request.POST or None)
if input_form.is_valid():
    # Handle success scenario
else:
    # Handle error scenario

# Or if using djangorestframework
input_serializer = InputSerializer(data=request.data)
input_serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
```